# How to group using LINQ, then get value of largest group

Tags: c#, linq

Here's what I have so far:

```
  var bestReason =
   from p in successfulReasons
   group p by p.Reason into g
   select new { Excuse = g.Key, ExcuseCount = g.Count() };
```

What I need to do now is return one reason that is the best reason, determined by which were successful in the past.

Sample data:

```
ID,Reason
---------
0,Weather
1,Traffic
2,Illness
3,Weather
4,Traffic
5,Traffic
6,Pirates
```

should return "Traffic"

Would like to do it all in one LINQ statement, if possible.

Thanks.

EDIT:  If there are 7 Pirate Attacks, and 7 Traffic Accidents, I'm ok with returning either one (the first alphabetically would be fine).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var bestReason = successfulReasons
    .GroupBy(r => r.Reason)
    .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
    .First().Key;
```

Comment: should be  `.First().Key` at the end imo

Comment: Thanks.  I kept trying to somehow implement Max().  OrderByDescending() and First() work great.

So, how do I mark an answer when two people said basically the same thing?  I think I like the LINQiness (is that a word?) of this one more (i.e. how each command works with the results of the previous).

Comment: @Slightly A - I believe there is a minimum time before you can accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do:

```
string bestReason =
    (from p in successfulReasons
     orderby p.Reason
     group p by p.Reason into g
     orderby g.Count() descending
     select g.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: When you call Count() on your IQueryable<IGrouping<>>, aren't you converting your IQueryable into an IEnumerable<Excuse> multiple times? One time per IGrouping<>? Ultimately, I'm intrigued to see what kind of SQL calls this type of code generates.

Comment: @weirdlover, that's a very good question. Most of the time I'm using LINQ to objects or to XML, so I never had a chance to try that with the SQL provider.

Comment: OK. Answered my own question. Looks like LINQ is smart enough to generate one succinct ...SELECT TOP 1... call. Pretty cool, actually.

Comment: Added the generated SQL to my answer -- and I'm giving you the upvote for answering the question correctly. Thanks for forcing me to look under the hood! Cheers, E

Answer (score 1):

```
 var group = excuses.GroupBy(m => m.Reason)
      .OrderByDescending(m => m.Count())
      .Select(m => m.Key)
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Which produces the following sql statement:

```
SELECT TOP (1) [t1].[Reason]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], [t0].[Reason]
    From [dbo].[Excuses] As [t0]
    GROUP BY [t0].[Reason]
    ) As [t1]
ORDER BY [t1].[value] DESC
```

Since this is a moderately complicated IQueryable expression, you might consider compiling it to speed up the response time:

```
Func<ExcusesDataContext, string> commonResult = CompiledQuery.Compile(
    (ExcusesDataContext c) => c.Excuses.GroupBy(m => m.Reason).OrderByDescending(m => m.Count()).Select(m => m.Key).FirstOrDefault()
);

Console.WriteLine(commonResult(new ExcusesDataContext()));
Console.ReadLine();
```

You could also just call the stored procedure via a repository and snag the particular value that you're looking for. This would be the fastest path to happiness, but the least fun to maintain:

```
string excuse = this.repo.Excuses.MostCommonFor(ProblemList.BeingLate);
```